# "Could not find main method from given launch configuration" error when exporting jar from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build, jar, export

I developed my program using Eclipse as my IDE. I used to use `File|Export| Runnable JAR file` option for creating dist build for client.

I was working with project using Run or (often) Debug button in eclipse (so I have configuration for project with valid main method).

Unfortunately when I created build yesterday I had following error when I tried to run app:

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from My.jar
```

Then when I retried exporting I found the following problem in export log:

```
Could not find main method from given launch configuration
```

I have no idea what could cause this problem. I think I hadn't change anything in my project configuration. And I'm test my builds so I'm sure this option used to work correctly.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Sometimes you may need to restart your DIE if you use one. [See this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527869/could-not-find-main-method-from-given-launch-configuration-when-using-javasca

Comment: Sometimes you may need to restart your IDE if you use one. [See this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527869/could-not-find-main-method-from-given-launch-configuration-when-using-javasca

Comment: You may need to restart your IDE if you use one. See this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527869/could-not-find-main-method-from-given-launch-configuration-when-using-javasca

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you selecting correct 'Launch Configuration' in the export dialog? Make sure it's from your project.

Also, once exported you could unzip jar file and look into 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' file - there should be 'Main-Class' entry with fully qualified name of your class where the main() method is.

Comment: Thanks for answerer. Yes I dubele checked that I selected valid Launch Configuration during export.
One more thing can I just edit this file and crate new zip (jar)? Won't it change jar checksum or something (sorry for noobish question)?

Comment: I found answer for repacking question: "They can also use zip tools to do so; however, caution should be exercised as to the order of entries in the zip file headers as the manifest likely needs to be first." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)

Comment: I accepting your answer because of two reasons:1. you help me to solve my problem (I used jar tool instead of zip). 2. after googling a little I think it's possible that better answer then "it eclipse bug" not exist.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and none of the other options worked. Even removing and starting with a new workspace.  In my case the problem was that I hadn't manually added the "classes" directory of my project to the classpath of the debug configuration that I was using to debug the java app. I don't know why it didn't pick up the classes directory automatically as part of the project from which I was running the app. In any case it started working again after that.

Answer (score 2):

just had the same problem :s
it's annoying but easy to manually fix in the manifest file.

1. open the .jar file with winrar or 7zip.
2. locate the manifest file (META-INF folder)
3. change it to this.

`Manifest-Version: 1.0
 main-class: (package).(main-class)`

In my case i had it in the default package.

`Manifest-Version: 1.0
 main-class: run`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to find your class file in Launch configuration, Right click on your project - > run as Java Application.  Now export again.