# not find main method while exporting runnable jar with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I have this problem when I try to export runnable jar. I'm using eclipse oxygen and JDK 9.

[image]

Comment: In NetBeans (another IDE) there's a command (menu option) to set the main class.  You'd have to do something similar in Eclipse.  Google for that phrase plus "Eclipse" and see what comes up.

Comment: Better to bring the code here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Could not find main method from given launch configuration" when using Java+Scala+Slick2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527869/could-not-find-main-method-from-given-launch-configuration-when-using-javasca)

Comment: Read the [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46475709/java-9-eclipse-4-7-portable-export-error-resource-not-found-could-not-find-m) as well.

Comment: I think this is a new Oxygen problem. I have the same one. I have tried to put a mainfest.fm file in the project, but eclipse ignores it.  Export a jar allows you to select the manifest file and puts it in the jar, puts a blank one in the META-INF dir.  Export executable jar builds a 1KB file with only a blank manifest file.