# Java - Export Executable Jar -> Can't find main class

Tags: java, eclipse, powershell, jar

I got this Java Code that works fine when I let it run in Powershell but when I try to export an executabe jar in Eclipse I get:

> JAR creation failed. See details for additional information.
>     No resources selected
>     Jar export finished with problems. See details for additional information.
>       Could not find main method from given launch configuration.

Not sure what the problem is?

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115471/could-not-find-main-method-from-given-launch-configuration-error-when-exportin#4116301).

Comment: "Manifest-Version: 1.0" is in my manifest file, nothing else.

Comment: Can you post the full error trace?